# ASP.NET 4.6 Bundle Config not loading a file

Tags: asp.net, bundle

I am using a `BundleCollection` BundleConfig file in an ASP.NET 4.6 application.  It has been working fine but recently starting skipping one of the files in the Bundle.  Ex:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MyBundle").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/Views/Shared/App.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Views/Shared/Logging.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Views/Shared/Utilities.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Views/Shared/Resources.js",
                    "~/Scripts/Views/Shared/Security.js"));
```

There is no mini-fication or optimization going on yet.  On the home page it loads fine, but on clicking through to another page the same Bundle call leaves out the `"~/Scripts/Views/Shared/App.js",` file, yet it loads the rest of them.  There are no errors in App.js either.  I tried re-installing my project from TFS and updating all NuGet packages. Any ideas as to what could cause this?

Comment: I eventually found a work around which is to place `"~/Scripts/Views/Shared/Empty.js"` in front of the App.js line and an empty JavaScript file in the project, run the program, and then remove it and run again.  Seems that somehow BundleConfig is caching things somewhere.